# Storing JSON data in mobile cache memory in Android

Tags: android, json

I open this page and sync with the server and display the records and and data I get back from the server. I want to improve the performance of my app. I am new to cache memory so please help me or give me some other idea to make my app faster.

```
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Categry.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_search, "GET", params);
        Log.d("Search idioms: ", json.toString());
        try {
// Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

             if (success == 1) {
// products found
// Getting Array of Products
            idioms = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IDIOMS);

// looping through All Products
            for (int i = 0; i < idioms.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = idioms.getJSONObject(i);

// Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String entry = c.getString(TAG_ENTRY);
                String meaning = c.getString(TAG_MEANING);

// creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_ENTRY, entry);
                map.put(TAG_MEANING, meaning);
// adding HashList to ArrayList
                idiomsList.add(map);
               }
            } else {
// no idioms found
//do something
                //tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        /*catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
        catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {


            pDialog.dismiss();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
/**
 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
 * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Categry.this, idiomsList,
                            R.layout.activity_list_child, new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_ENTRY, TAG_MEANING},
                            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.entry, R.id.meaning});

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), homescreen.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        //   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_categry, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), qrcode.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), homescreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read and use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: i open app the data loading only one time .......after that i want get my data from only in local memory

Comment: Cache your complete json string into the `SharedPreferences` and use it any time you want to.

Comment: thank you for your reply i will check this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save Json object to cache with the following code...

```
          try {
                ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream
                            (new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "") + File.separator + "cacheFile.srl"));
                    out.writeObject(jsonObj.toString());
                    out.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And if you want to read the json object from cache u can use the below code..

```
        try {
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream
                        (new File(getActivity().getCacheDir() + File.separator + "cacheFile.srl")));
                jsonObj = new JSONObject((String) in.readObject());
                in.close();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OptionalDataException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are full and full dealing with json and making app smoother means use the library called [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) by square its very simple and easily integrated with your json then you can store it as a json file for offline access